# convert time to minute and second

Tags: javascript

can anyway help me to generate a function in jquery that convert time() to seconds

example: 1336333809 = 9 minutes and 23 seconds?

like this function i found but whew it's seconds to hour

```
function secondsToTime(secs)
{
    var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));

    var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);

    var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);

    var obj = {
        "h": hours,
        "m": minutes,
        "s": seconds
    };
    return obj;
}
```

if anyway has a solution please share :D

Comment: 1336333809 is more than 42 years. You have to keep dividing it out.

Comment: Am I the only one who does not understand the question?

Comment: 1336333809 = 9 minutes and 23 seconds, really?

Comment: if 1336333809 is 371203 hours, 50 minutes, 9 seconds then I have an answer.

Comment: @HannibalBurr: How did you get these "_9 minutes and 23 seconds_" from _1336333809_?

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with the native [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object?

```
function secondsToTime(seconds) {

    var date = new Date(seconds * 1000);

    var obj = {
        "h": date.getHours(),
        "m": date.getMinutes(),
        "s": date.getSeconds()
    };
}
```

Comment: almost got it bro, but its timeToSeconds :D hmmm

Comment: @HannibalBurr sorry but I don't understand what you mean